# Value on Y Axis of a Bar chart is too large

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have A BAR chart in SSRS which has following vaues..

for 5 points on X-axis values are 100,120,130,123,8000
So the last value is too lagre due to which scale is geeting larger causing chart to look bad...n unreadable  for other points...

So is there any way by wiz i can breal the LAST BAR in a bar chart showing it on ongoing manner with data point lable on top of the bar....

i trid it by giving max value on Y axis but it cuases DATA point lable to disappear hence the catual value of the bar is unknown to user.....

Answer (score 1):

Use a logarithmic scale? ;)